# How to get disk usage statistics for remote network share?

Tags: .net, c++, windows, winapi, network-protocols

If I have a network share say `\\myfileserver\documents`, can I find out programmatically how much disk space it is using (used/free space) using any API of some sort?

Please note it could be hosted by samba or it could be on a san storage device which means I won't be able to install anything on that machine to check the local disk usage and report it via some web service.

I'm writing code in .NET but I'm sure that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937.aspx) explicitly documents how you need to pass a UNC path: include the trailing backslash.